# About the infinite geometrical sequence factored with n

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, infinity

I just came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533039/prove-geometric-sequence-question) thread, and i asked myself:

I know that $\sum^\infty_{n=0} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$

But what happens when we set up the sum like

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0} nx^n = ?$$

There is probably a formula for that as well, at least there must be some coincidence, for the limited sums i already saw the prove in the thread i mentioned above. My books could not help me out so far.. If there is a formula for this, i would also like to see the derivation of it..

Searched the web with no luck so far. If you know a website or thread where this is explained, probably a link is enough for an answer.. I appreciate your help!

Comment: $$\sum^\infty_{n=\color{red}0} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Comment: yes right, updated.

Comment: This is asked several times every week on this site, I think...

Comment: I really searched for it on this site. Weird that i didn't find something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for $|x| < 1$, we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n = x \sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1} = x \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d\ }{dx} x^n =  x \frac{d\ }{dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = x \frac{d\ }{dx} \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

You can now write down an expression for your sum.

Comment: $= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} $? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate the first expression with respect to $x$, then multiply by $x$, then add missing initial term(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is quite what you're looking for, but I know I have used this one is class before and if'd you'd like to look I've also used it in a question that i posted on here. Hope it helps!

$$\sum_{k=1}^nku^k={u\over (1-u)^2}\bigg[nu^{n+1}-(n+1)u^n+1\bigg]\forall u\ge 1$$

**P.S.-** I know it's not for $k=0$ to $n$, but i thought it might help still.